# Huawei AppGallery : App Release Date mismatching and App Status not showing anything

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

App Release Date mismatching and App Status showing empty
a) App has released three months back but date showing in App Gallery is
b) in the version information App status and Review comments are empty.
find the attached image
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the version code in the apk package and resubmit. If the version code does not change, the “update date” displayed in AppGallery will be affected.
Please follow the below link for the  detailed information:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-update_app